# Building carrot2 source code in Java

Tags: eclipse, carrot2

I'm trying to compile Carrot2 code in Eclipse but I'm getting a lot of warnings:

> .apt_generated/ is missing from source..

etc

Do you have any idea please?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Eclipse are you using? Did you follow the steps to set up your project outlined here? http://download.carrot2.org/head/manual/index.html#section.integration.setting-up-carrot2-sources-in-eclipse

Comment: Yes I have. I am using jdk 1.7 if that helps.